# Sharing only some fields of a struct between threads

Tags: multithreading, rust

I'm writing a simulation program using two threads: one for the actual simulation and the other for rendering.

The simulation thread has a `Vec` of `Entity` structs that it uses each tick. My problem arises when the rendering thread needs to access the `Vec` of entities in order to render them, but some of the fields of the `Entity` struct do not implement the `Send` trait. However, these fields are not actually used for rendering.

The only solution I have thought of is to split each entity into two structs: one which contains the internal 'non-sendable' fields and the other which contains the fields necessary for rendering. I could then use two separate `Vec`s and wrap the 'sendable' one in a `Mutex` and share it with the rendering thread. However this means I will have two parts to each entity and that each struct will have to store the index of the other part to keep them tied together, but this feels like a massive headache to manage when entities are being created and deleted a lot.

Is there a standard way of doing this in Rust? It feels like a fairly common requirement for lots of programs, but I can't find an easy way to do it.

Comment: Rust objects that don't implement `Send` are actually very rare - only `Rc` and `RefCell` come to mind, as do raw pointers. What are the non-Send types of your fields?

Comment: If your fields must remain non-`Send`, one possible solution that doesn't involve splitting the entities is to use the (inappropriately named) [`fragile` crate](https://crates.io/crates/fragile). Then you can wrap the non-`Send` fields in `Fragile<T>` which will prevent their use outside of the original thread (using a run-time check), but will allow the whole object to be passed to other threads, and will allow you to use the fields that are actually `Send`.

Comment: The non-`Send` types are from the pyo3 crate so they're unavoidable - I'll look into the fragile crate, it looks very promising

Comment: Hope it helps, good luck. Out of curiosity, what pyo3 types are non-Send? From looking at pyo3 docs, I understand that its wrappers around Python objects are `Send` and `Sync`, but using them requires presenting the `Python` GIL token as proof of having acquired the GIL. E.g. [`Py<T>`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/0.13.2/pyo3/prelude/struct.Py.html) is `Send` and `Sync`.

Comment: I was using the type `PyAny` which does not implement `Send` or `Sync`. I've now wrapped this value in the `Py` type leaving a `Py<PyAny>` which can actually be sent between threads! I'm still going to use the ECS design in the answer though as it will make my program more efficient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track with the split-`Entity` design, but you can take it one step further with cues from the [Entity-Component-System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system) (ECS) pattern. Rather than having a `Vec<SimEntity>` and a `Vec<RenderEntity>`, in which the two kinds of `Entity` must keep track of each other, the ECS pattern says that an *entity* is simply a collection of *components*. In a simple model, this would be something like

```rust
struct Sim { /* ... */ }
struct Render { /* ... */ }

struct Entity {
    sim_id: usize,
    render_id: usize,
}

struct World {
    entities: Vec<Entity>,
    sims: Vec<Sim>,
    renders: Arc<Mutex<Vec<Render>>>,
}
```

Then, a *system* in ECS terms is simply a function that acts on components rather than entities. This pattern parallelizes well because a given system can lock only those components which it needs, rather than locking all entity data. Here's a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b2506c415cb152ae9716f4790f51fffe) with a simple (and somewhat naive) proof-of-concept with a separate rendering thread which shares data with the simulation thread.

If you're looking for an implementation or inspiration, Rust has [numerous ECS libraries](https://arewegameyet.rs/ecosystem/ecs/). You can find extensive benchmarks of the various options in [rust-gamedev/ecs-bench-suite](https://github.com/rust-gamedev/ecs_bench_suite).

Comment: I assume this system doesn't support entities being removed from the list?